# Update main dataframe based on sub dataframes coming from groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, pandas-groupby

I am pretty new to pandas and trying to learn it. So, any advice would be appreciated :)

This is just a small part of my whole dataframe `DF2`:

|  | Chromosome_Name | Sequence_Source | Sequence_Feature | Start | End | Strand | Gene_ID | Gene_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | ensembl_havana | gene | 14363 | 34806 | - | "ENSG00000227232" | "WASH7P" |
| 1 | 1 | havana | gene | 89295 | 138566 | - | "ENSG00000238009" | "RP11-34P13.7" |
| 2 | 1 | havana | gene | 141474 | 178862 | - | "ENSG00000241860" | "RP11-34P13.13" |
| 3 | 1 | havana | gene | 227615 | 272253 | - | "ENSG00000228463" | "AP006222.2" |
| 4 | 1 | ensembl_havana | gene | 312720 | 453948 | + | "ENSG00000237094" | "RP4-669L17.10" |

These are my conditions:

```
Condition 1: Reference row's "Start" value <= Other row's "End" value.
Condition 2: Reference row's "End" value >= Other row's "Start" value.
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
chromosome_list = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","X","Y"]

dataFrame = DF2.groupby(["Chromosome_Name"])

for chromosome in chromosome_list:
  CHR = dataFrame.get_group(chromosome)
  for i in range(0, len(CHR)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(CHR)):
      Overlap_index = DF2[(DF2.loc[i, ["Chromosome_Name"] == chromosome]) & (DF2.loc[i, ["Start"]] <= DF2.loc[j, ["End"]]) & (DF2.loc[i, ["End"]] >= DF2.loc[j, ["Start"]])].index

DF2 = DF2.drop(Overlap_index )
```

The `chromosome_list` is all the unique values of column `"Chromosome_Name"`.

Mainly, I want to check for each row that whether the columns (`"Start"` and `"End"`) values are satisfying the conditions above. I believe I need to iterate a single row (reference row) over the particular rows found in the data frame. However, to achieve this I need to consider the value of the first column `"Chromosome_Name"`.

More specifically, every row in `DF2` should be checked according to the conditions stated above but, for example, a row at `Chromosome_Name` = 5 shouldn't be checked with the row of `Chromosome_Name` = 12. Therefore, first, I thought that I should split the dataframe using `pd.groupby()` according to `Chromosome_Name` then, using these dataframes' indexes, I could manipulate (drop the given rows from) the `DF2`. However, it did not work :)

**P.S.** After `DF2` is splitted into sub dataframes (according to unique `Chromosome_Name`), each sub dataframe has different size. e.g. There are 641 rows at `Chromosome_Name` = X but there are 19342 rows for the `Chromosome_Name` = 1

If you know how to correct my code or provide me another solution, I would be glad.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to pandas too so I do not want to give you a wrong insight and advices but have you ever thougth of converting `Start` and `End` columns to lists. So that you can use if statement if you are not comfortable with pandas but your task is urgent. However, I am aware that converting dataframe into list would be something opposite to the creation of pandas.